# Objective c implement method which takes array of arguments

Tags: objective-c, arrays, methods

Hee

Does anybody know how to implement an method in objective c that will take an array of arguments as parameter such as:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",nil];
```

The method declaration for this method is:

```
+ (id)arrayWithObjects:(id)firstObj...
```

I can't seem to make such method on my own. I did the following:

```
+ (void) doSometing:(id)string manyTimes:(NSInteger)numberOfTimes;

[SomeClass doSometing:@"A",@"B",nil manyTimes:2];
```

It will give the warningtoo many arguments to function 'doSometing:manyTimes:'

Thanks already.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ellipsis (...) is inherited from C; you can use it only as the final argument in a call (and you've missed out the relevant comma in your example). So in your case you'd probably want:

```
+ (void)doSomethingToObjects:(id)firstObject, ...;
```

or, if you want the count to be explicit and can think of a way of phrasing it well:

```
+ (void)doManyTimes:(NSInteger)numberOfTimes somethingToObjects:(id)firstObject, ...;
```

You can then use the normal C methods for dealing with ellipses, which reside in stdarg.h. There's a quick documentation of those [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/stdarg.h.html), example usage would be:

```
+ (void)doSomethingToObjects:(id)firstObject, ...
{
    id object;
    va_list argumentList;

    va_start(argumentList, firstObject);
    object = firstObject;

    while(1)
    {
        if(!object) break; // we're using 'nil' as a list terminator

        [self doSomethingToObject:object];
        object = va_arg(argumentList, id);
    }

    va_end(argumentList);
}
```

EDIT: additions, in response to comments. You can't pass the various things handed to you in an ellipsis to another function that takes an ellipsis due to the way that C handles function calling (which is inherited by Objective-C, albeit not obviously so). Instead you tend to pass the va_list. E.g.

```
+ (NSString *)doThis:(SEL)selector makeStringOfThat:(NSString *)format, ...
{
    // do this
    [self performSelector:selector];

    // make string of that...

    // get the argument list
    va_list argumentList;
    va_start(argumentList, format);

    // pass it verbatim to a suitable method provided by NSString
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:argumentList];

    // clean up
    va_end(argumentList);

    // and return, as per the synthetic example
    return [string autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Is there also a way to take ellipsis as parameter and then pass is over to another method?

Comment: @Mats: you normally get the va_list and pass that on (hence, e.g. vprintf, or NSString -initWithFormat:arguments:). You can't just pass on whatever is described by the ellipsis (as in, have an ellipsis function call another) since the C runtime isn't required to know how much stuff is there and therefore can't copy it.

Comment: Can you give a code example with passing a ellipsis to a second objective-c method?

Comment: You can't actually pass the ellipsis. You have to pass the va_list. Example added.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple arguments (also known as an arglist) can only come at the end of a method declaration. Your `doSomething` method would look something like this:

```
+ (void)doNumberOfTimes:(NSInteger)numberOfTimes withStrings:(id)firstArg, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstArg);

    NSString * argString = firstArg;
    while (argString != nil)
    {
        // do something with argString here

        argString = va_arg(args, NSString *);
    }

    va_end(args);
}
```

To be called as follows:

```
[SomeClass doNumberOfTimes:2 withStrings:@"A", @"B", nil];
```

See also: [How to create variable argument methods in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804674/how-to-create-variable-argument-methods-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're after a variadic function. Here's Apple's documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa2005/qa1405.html