# Objective C : Cocoa : 2 sets of variable arguments?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

It is possible to have a method  in this manner:

```
[obj mergeObjs:obj1,obj2,obj3,nil];
```

Or have a method in this manner:

```
[obj mergeObjs:obj1,obj2...obj(n),nil usingBlocks:blk1,blk2,blk3....blk(m),nil];
```

where n may or may not be equal to m.

Basically **multiple variable argument lists** in a single method declaration. ?

This is not a potential answer:

```
[obj merge:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...,nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...,nil]...,nil]];
```

Thanks in advance.

Here is the link i found for Single Variable Argument Lists:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html 
[How to create variable argument methods in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804674/how-to-create-variable-argument-methods-in-objective-c)

Comment: isn't the answer already given? have you tried? `- (type) method1: (type)A, ... method2: (type)B, ...;` looks strange but have you tried?

Comment: What do you want to do ? what is your problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Message dispatch boils down to a call to `objc_msgSend()` (or one of its variants). That follows the C calling convention and there's no way to express the multiple variable argument lists in that convention.

Answer (score 5):

You can't achieve this with a variable length argument list, but have you considered just passing two arrays?

```
[obj mergeObjs:(NSArray*)objs usingBlocks:(NSArray*)blocks];
```

Modern versions of clang (the Objective C compiler used by recent Xcode releases) even support `NSArray` literals

```
[instance mergeObjs:@[obj1, obj2, obj3] usingBlocks:@[^{}, ...]];
```

(Of course, making sure to copy your blocks appropriately for insertion into an NSArray).

Answer (score 0):

Concluding based on the responses &  a serious loss of hair -
It it not possible to have 2 variable argument lists in a method declaration.

The purpose of having mulit-Variable-argument-list was to provide more readability in my context.

Will make do with Arrays... Sigh!!.

Comment: This is not an answer it is a comment!